# Custom UITableViewCell button.backgroundColor gets changed automatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom tablevVewCell linked to TableViewCell.swift the cell has a button which changes button color to green when touchedUpInside, but when a new cell (dequeue reusable property) is created the new cell button also has the changed(green) color I also tried handling this using if-else but no help.Thanks for all the help (also I am dealing with multiple sections here). Basically my question is how to know that the button in the class TableViewCell is tapped and assign a value in the MainVC?

MainVC :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    if objArray.count > 0 {
        cell.courseCode.text = objArray[indexPath.section].code
        cell.courseName.text = objArray[indexPath.section].name
        cell.slot.text = objArray[indexPath.section].slot
        cell.year.text = objArray[indexPath.section].year
        cell.button.tag = indexPath.section
    }

    return cell
}
```

TableViewCell :

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var courseName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var courseCode: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var slot: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var year: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var downloadButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    var buttonIsSelected:Bool = false

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
        print(button.tag)
        buttonIsSelected = true
        button.backgroundColor = .green
    }

}
```

Comment: dont change button color in @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any).You have to do in cellForRowAt .By checking this variable status buttonIsSelected.

Comment: @Sakshi how do I access the function of button from cellForRowAt() ? I am really sorry to ask such questions, I am a beginner

Comment: cell.button.backgroundColor = buttonIsSelected ? .green : .white

Answer (score 0):

Your object from `objArray` should have some property

```
var isSelected: Bool
```

then when user press button you should change this property of button (using delegate pattern for example).

Last thing what you have to do is set background color of button in data source method `cellForRowAt` based on item's `isSelected` property

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...
    let item = objArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.button.backgroundColor = item.isSelected ? .green : .white //default
    ...
}
```

**Note:** instead of using `indexPath.section` use `indexPath.row`

---

Alternatively if you don't need to have this `isSelected` property in your custom model you can make your `objArray` a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

When you are dequeuing the cell, you are basically taking an old cell which has already been created but not in use.

Thus, if you have set the cell's backgroundColor to green through clicking button, when you dequeue it, the color will remain green.

There are two things you need to here.

1. Add a field of color to your model object.. To indicate which of the cell's background has already changed color to green.

then in cellForRow method

you will have something like this

```
cell.button.backgroundColor = objc[indexPath.section].hasChangedToGreen ? .green : nil
```

2. Inside your TableViewCell class implement this

   override func prepareForReuse(){
   super.prepareForResult()
   button.backgroundColor = nil 
   }

Answer (score 0):

You are in need to keep track of buttons selected and not selected for all cells

1. Create an array `var buttonState = [Bool]()`
2. This array should be equal to length of your `objArray`
3. Initially it will have all false value
4. Do not give indexPath.section as tag to cell instead use indexPath.row

Now in you viewController user following code

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapButton(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        if objArray.count>0{
            cell.courseCode.text = objArray[indexPath.section].code
            cell.courseName.text = objArray[indexPath.section].name
            cell.slot.text = objArray[indexPath.section].slot
            cell.year.text = objArray[indexPath.section].year
            cell.button.tag = indexPath.row
        }
    if buttonState[indexpath.row] {
    cell.button.backgroundColor = .green
   }
    else{
      cell.button.backgroundColor = defaultColor `//color of you choice`
    }
        return cell
    }

     @objc func didTapButton(sender:UIButton){
    print(button.tag)
    let state = buttonState[button.tag]
    if !state{
        button.backgroundColor = .green
        buttonState[sender.tag] = true
       }
    }
```

and change your custom cell class to this

```
 class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var courseName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var courseCode: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var slot: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var year: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var downloadButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }


    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please write in the button action method:

```
 @IBAction func button (_ sender: Any) {
     let btn = sender as! UIButton
     btn.isSelected = !btn.isSelected
}
```

Then in CellForRowAtIndexPath method check this condition :

```
    if cell.button.isSelected {
       //Your colour
    } else {
       //Your colour
    }
```

It may helps you. Thank you